# FeatherJS- authenticate("jwt") - Authenticate but avoid calling User Get service?

Tags: feathersjs, feathers-authentication

In my single page application once I login with FeathersJS authentication I am passing my JWT token to the server for further service requests . In my service hook I am using `authenticate("jwt")`  to check for authentication . It is working perfect , but also populating `context.params.user` with the user information . So  `authenticate("jwt")` calling `user` `get` service for every API call which has authentication enabled .

1) If I don't need any user information other the the `user ID` can I avoid this `user` `get` service call ?  Or is there any other specific reason to populate user object ?

2) By avoiding the above call , Can I just populate context.params.user only with the ID ( From the JWT token? )?

Thank You

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no way to avoid populating the user object right now unless you want to extend various internals of feathers authentication to do so.

Comment: Thank You @ccummings for your response . I thought there will be some flag , But thats fine .  What I want to avoid is one extra call to the database for each request .